# SAS ODS (proper data output) with cloud-only access?

Tags: sas

So I have SAS Enterprise Guide 6.1 which connects to SAS system via cloud access (main system itself is physically located at my university I think).

Now I want to output a few tables and place them into a LaTeX document. I am unsure how that will work out but some searching yields examples such as

```
ods tagsets.latex file="C:\SAS\mydata.tex";
proc print data=work.mydata;
...
run;
ods tagsets.latex close;
```

The obvious problem here is that the remote SAS system does not have access to actually create files freely on my computer (and I don't have access to create files freely on that remote machine).

Could I possibly have the results printed on the screen or some other workaround?

Comment: Do you, perhaps, have a shared drive that allows you to pass data to the server?  If not, how do you get data to the server?

Comment: @DomPazz I use the "Import Data" feature to send my data set to the temporary SAS library (WORK) on the remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in the work directory, and then use the "Copy Files" task to download them to your local PC.  You define the filename like so:

```
%let workdir = %sysfunc(getoption(work));
filename tempfile "&workdir.\myfile.ext"; *ext = extension for your file;
```

Then use that fileref in your ODS statement.  Finally, you can use Copy Files to bring it down to your local machine.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2013/05/20/export-and-download-any-file-from-sas-enterprise-guide/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `FILENAME` statement (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/65040/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p05r9vhhqbhfzun1qo9mw64s4700.htm).

Candidate methods are `URL, FTP, WEBDAV`.
Also you could create a file and use `FILENAME  EMAIL` to send it.

Quick tip how this could look like:

```
filename foo url 'http://www.mysite.com/test.tex';

filename foo "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))\test.tex";/* you should be able to write here */

ods tagsets.latex file=foo;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods tagsets.latex close;

filename foo clear;
```

Comment: Creating it in a WORK library doesn't work (ERROR: Error in the FILENAME statement.), I think in this case there might be some compatibility problems related to non-native SAS files in its library. But hopefully I'll get some other options to work.

Comment: If you have an error in the filename statement, then you did it wrong.  An issue with file types would give you a different error.  The SAS work library is just a normal directory, nothing special.